# JSON: Single item and an array for the same property?

Tags: json

Is it normal practice to change the type of a property from an array to a single item when there is only one occurrence?

```
[
  {
    "sport": [
      "Football",
      "Hockey"
    ]
  },
  {
    "sport": "Football"
  }
]
```

And how would you convert this data into programming objects when you don't know if it's an array or an object?

Relates to: [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: I would just keep it an array. What are your considerations for making it a string with only a single item? I can only think of downsides. As the related question shows you need a custom JSON converter. So if you can choose how to generate the JSON Object I would keep it an array.

Comment: I do not want to do this. I'm in a place where i have to handle this situation, so i want to know if this is normal practice.

Comment: That makes sense. It's not normal practice as far as I know. I've never seen that practice as far as my memory serves me. I can't think of a reason to do this since the only benefit I can think of is a small code reduction because you don't have to write a loop. But the JSON converter code completly removes this benefit.